# Proof Check for Topology Problem (Continuity)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I wanted to see if anyone can verify if my proof is correct. I ask because I end up not using all the assumptions given by the problem. The problem is

Let X and Y be first countable spaces. Prove that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous whenever $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ implies $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$.

*Proof*: We deny the consequent. Let $f$ not be continuous and $H$ be open in Y such that $f(x) \in H$. Since X is first countable there are open

$$ G_{1} \supset G_{2} \supset G_{3} \supset \ldots $$

such that $x \in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} G_{n} $. Since $f$ is not continuous, it follows that we can select $x_{n} \in G_{n}$ such that $f(x_{n}) \not\in H$. Thus $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ while $f(x_{n}) \not\rightarrow f(x)$. $\square$

Again, I ask because I only used the fact that X was first countable, I never ended up using the fact that Y was first countable. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your proof is not properly written.

Let $f$ be not continuous at $a$. Then there exists an open set $W$ in $Y$ containing $f(a) $ such that $\forall $ open sets $U$ containing $a$ we have $f(U)\nsubseteq W$.

Since $X$ is first countable,hence it has a countable base at $a$,so there exists a decreasing countable sequence of open sets $G_1\supset G_2\supset\ldots G_n\supset \ldots$  such that $a\in G_i$. Form a sequence $(x_n)$ where $x_n\in G_n$ and $x_n\to a$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(a)$

- first countabilty of $Y$ is not needed.

Comment: You just pick $x_n \in G_n$ such that $f(x_n) \notin W$, which exists by assumption. Any sequence $a_n$ with $a_n \in G_n$ converges to $a$ as the $G_n$ form a decreasing neighbourhood base.

Comment: I appreciate the response learnmore, but I'm having trouble seeing what, beyond designating that f is not continuous at a specific point, is wrong with the way my proof has been written. Moreover, I don't quite even see how, beyond differences in notation, your proof differs from mine. In any case, thank you for the verification!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is correct, but you’ve left out quite a few details that really ought to be stated explicitly. You’ve left a bit too much to the reader, and in at least one place what you’ve said isn’t quite what you need. It’s not enough that $x\in\bigcap_nG_n$: it’s crucial that the sets $G_n$ be a local base at $x$. Here’s a more careful version.

> Suppose that $f$ is not continuous. Then there are a point $x\in X$ and an open nbhd $H$ of $f(x)$ such that $f^{-1}[H]$ does not contain any open nbhd of $x$. $X$ is first countable, so there is a local base $\{G_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ at $x$ such that $G_0\supseteq G_1\supseteq G_2\supseteq\ldots\;$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ we know that $G_n\nsubseteq f^{-1}[H]$, so we can choose $x_n\in G_n\setminus f^{-1}[H]$. Then $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to x$, but for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $f(x_n)\notin H$, so $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\not\to f(x)$.